# PHP contact form not submitting textarea

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have tried looking at other related questions, and I have even asked some developer friends for help, but nothing has helped me fix my contact form. I have a basic PHP form, but on submit, I am missing the message textarea field in the email.

FORM CODE:

```
<form action="sendContactForm.php" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 large-12">
                        <div class="row formRow">
                            <div class="small-3 large-3 columns">
                                <label for="name" class="right inline">Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-9 large-9 columns">
                                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Firstname Lastname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 large-12">
                        <div class="row formRow">
                            <div class="small-3 large-3 columns">
                                <label for="email" class="right inline">Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-9 large-9 columns">
                                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="you@email.com">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 large-12">
                        <div class="row formRow">
                            <div class="small-3 large-3 columns">
                                <label for="company" class="right">Company Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-9 large-9 columns">
                                <input name="company" type="text" id="company" placeholder="eg: Apple, Google, Microsoft">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 large-12">
                        <div class="row formRow">
                            <div class="small-3 large-3 columns">
                                <label for="description" class="right inline">Details</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-9 large-9 columns">
                                <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="Please say a few words about why you are contacting me. If this is a project request, some good things to include are: project type, budget, deadline, and expected results."></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 large-12">
                        <div class="row formRow">
                            <div class="small-12 large-9 large-offset-3 columns">
                                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button expand"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
   // from the form
   $name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
   $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
   $company = trim(strip_tags($_POST['company']));
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $body = $name."\n".$company."\n".$message."\n";
   // set here
   $subject = "Contact form submitted!";
   $to = 'kempfjj@gmail.com';



   $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

   // send the email
   mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

   // redirect afterwords, if needed
   header('Location: index.html');
```

?>

I would really appreciate any help that a professional could give me on this.

Comment: There is no `message` area in this markup.

Comment: There's no reference to `description` in your processing code.

Comment: `$message = $_POST['message'];` should be `$message = $_POST['description'];`

Comment: You should `var_dump( $_POST )` when debugging these.

Comment: change the name of the textarea to message or get the description field in php file

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am seriously stunned that I missed that. F'in noob behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<textarea name="description" id="description"
```

while getting you are using different variable, change

```
 $message = $_POST['message'];
```

into

```
$message = $_POST['description'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `$message = $_POST['message'];` in your PHP code, but there is no input element with name `message` on the form, so it will be empty.

There is one  with the name `description` and you are not getting that out in PHP. So do you mean:

```
$message = $_POST['description'];
```

OR you could change the `name='description'` to `name='message'`on the input element on the form.

Comment: Yea. Somehow missed that. Thanks for taking the time to answer.